# How can i truncate / convert a decimel point to an integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have come across rails development few weeks ago. Right now, i am trying to solve an issue which demonstrates like below

i have a input field which converts any integer value X -> X.0
e.g -> if i input 15 hours -> then it converts 15.0 automatically which is fine

But if i input 15. OR .15 (dot before / after) -> it shows me error which is usual.

Would you please tell how can i convert it to the integer value only (even if i place dot before / after it should only comes up with plain integer without error.)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. It's a little unclear what exactly you're asking. If you could *edit your question* and add in the relevant section of code that you have tried, then we can alter it for you to work the way you'd like. (don't put code in the comments as the formatting is awful).

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far (your code) and what you'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use to_i to convert anything to integer http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i

Comment: HI Arun.. Thanks.. i tried in both way..... "16.".to_i and "16".to_i but i can't convert 16. -> just 16 numeric value

Comment: What was the error message

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass):
i have used a condition in a code which calculates estimated hours in a assigned project -> due_date - start_date + 1 == 2 && estimated_hours > "16.".to_i

Comment: Are you sure that variable estimated_hours is not null

Comment: No... it is not null

Comment: Something has to be nil. You should check the value of estimated_hours at this point. Also keep in mind that `".16".to_i` will return 0.

Comment: I also believe that the error is somewhere else

Comment: it is actually initialized as nil in my model file. ......... Code Line: validates :estimated_hours, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :allow_nil => true, :message => :invalid}

Comment: does that solve you problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
input.scan(/\d+/).first
```

which will return the first found number in the string.
For example:

```
"16.".scan(/\d+/).first
=> "16"

".16".scan(/\d+/).first
=> "16"
```

Then you will have the number as a string, which you can then convert to integer with `.to_i` or handle it in your way.

Comment: Hi .. i used -> estimated_hours > "16.".scan(/\d+/).last  But fact remains the same..